# MYSQL Left Join last row of result

Tags: mysql

I am in need of some MYSQL help.

I have a table called Tickets and a table called statusLogs how can I:

```
select 
  t.*,
  sl.statusId
from
  ticket LEFT JOIN (
    select * from statusLog where ticket_ticketId = t.ticketId order by statusLogId DESC LIMIT 1
  ) sl
```

Basically, I would like to select the last statusLog for a given ticket number in one statement.

Comment: Why not a trigger? take a look at this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26661314/best-and-optimal-way-to-join-max-value-from-other-table/26664982#26664982

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.  It joins a subselect of `statusLog` which pulls the highest (therefore most recent I think) `statusLogId` for each `ticket_ticketId`.  That retrieves the `statusLogId` for the ticket.  A further join then matches the `statusId` to the `statusLogId` located in the first join.

```
SELECT
  t.*,
  slid.statusId
FROM
  ticket t LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ticket_ticketId, MAX(statusLogId) AS statusLogId FROM statusLog GROUP BY ticket_ticketId
  ) sl ON t.ticketId = sl.ticket_ticketId
  JOIN statusLog slid ON slid.statusLogId = sl.statusLogId
```

Answer (score 25):

this is untested, but is one of my ways to do it:

```
SELECT t.*, sl1.statusId
FROM ticket AS t
LEFT JOIN statusLog AS sL1 ON t.ticketId = sL1.ticketId 
LEFT JOIN statusLog AS sL2 ON t.ticketId = sL2.ticketId AND sL1.statusLogId < sL2.statusLogId 
WHERE sL2.statusLogId IS NULL
```

Comment: this works wonderfully, but I don't understand why. You left join the same table twice under different aliases and somehow manage to avoid making any sub-queries. 
i'm using your solution under a similar setting, with a file table and file revision table. the file table keeps the name and path, and thje revision keeps comments, revision author, etc...

Comment: It's like saying "select from ticket join status log (sL1) where ticketIDs match and there are no newer statuses (sL2)"

Comment: For me second join selects second matching row instead of last one

Comment: It only works as expected when you only have 2 records, because it shows the second record and not the last one.