# Left Join MySql

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

I have been following this Left Join answer but cannot make mine work

[MYSQL Left Join last row of result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485786/mysql-left-join-last-row-of-result)

I have two tables

```
leicester

count   area_id  section   toberth
  1        LR       WL       300
  2        LR       WL       301
  3        ER       SN       300


berthmove

count   area_id    timemove    description    toberth
  1        LR        124          6R43           300
  2        LR        126          5RT4           300
  3        TR        128          6TF7           310
  4        LR        121          6TT3           301
  5        LR        122          5RR7           301
  6        TR        127          7YY9           300
```

Here is my code

```
  $stmt=$mysql_link->prepare("SELECT  l.*,b.* 
     FROM leicester AS l
     LEFT JOIN berthmove AS b ON l.toberth=b.toberth WHERE l.area_id=b.area_id AND l.section="WL"
     LEFT JOIN berthmove AS b2 ON l.toberth=b2.toberth AND b.timemove<b2.timemove
     WHERE b2.timemove is NULL LIMIT 1 ");      
     $stmt->execute();
```

I am trying to end up with descriptions 5RT4 and 5RR7 , ie rows 2 and 5 from the berthmove table. ie choose berth 300 and 301 from table 'leicester' (ie they are in section WL) and then find the description against 300 and 301. But it can be only the latest description (based on timemove) for each. Also need to check the area_id is the same.

Any help please

Heres the fetch

```
   foreach($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $berths)
     {
     echo "hello";
     $selectberth=$berths['toberth'];
     $description=$berths['descr'];
     echo $description;
     echo $selectberth;
     }
```

EDIT

Updated to code to reflect the change to the WHERE command and parsing issue

```
     $stmt=$mysql_link->prepare("SELECT  l.*,b.* 
     FROM leicester AS l
     LEFT JOIN berthmove AS b ON l.toberth=b.toberth
     LEFT JOIN berthmove AS b2 ON l.toberth=b2.toberth AND b.timemove<b2.timemove
     WHERE l.area_id=b.area_id AND l.section='WL' AND b2.timemove is NULL LIMIT 1 ");       
     $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: The `where` goes after all `join`s. You can only have 1 `where` in a `select`. Also `AND l.section="WL"` should be causing a parsing error and breaking your page load. Use error reporting.

Comment: Have moved the where to after all joins. I am getting a parsing error. It says unexpected T_string. Not sure what the problem is though

Comment: You weren't getting that error before? Read the full comment and correct the quotes.

Comment: Yes did have error before. Did not understand it. Have now changed "WL" to 'WL' . So now I get a correct result but only for 1 berth. It correctly picked the latest description but only for one of the berths?

Comment: Did you loop the `fetch`, and/or are you outputting in the `fetch` or after?

Comment: Yes. Included in edit above now. Think the Limit 1 maybe in the wrong place??

Comment: Oo well I missed the limit 1.. why do you have limit 1 if you want more than1

Comment: If I take the limit 1 off the code seems to hang now...the limit 1 was meant to show the latest (timewise) description for each berth. I think I need it but not sure how

Comment: It give you 1 row back, try limit 5

Comment: Interesting. Yes 5 gives back 5 different berths with the last description correctly. Which is right. The hanging I am seeing when I remove the limit must be the code just churning through the database. So I guess it must be very slow. berthmove is around 370k rows and leicester 157 rows

Comment: Do you have indexes on the columns you are joining on?

Comment: I don't. Going to add some. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Instead of finding the record having the maxium value of `timemove` for each group by joining berthmove to itself, try using a subquery for this, then use inner joins to find all the related information:

```
SELECT l.*, b2.*
FROM leicester l
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT area_id, toberth, max(timemove) as timemove
    FROM berthmove
    GROUP BY area_id, toberth) AS b1
ON l.area_id = b1.area_id AND l.toberth = b1.toberth
INNER JOIN berthmove b2
ON b1.area_id = b2.area_id
AND b1.toberth = b2.toberth
AND b1.timemove = b2.timemove
WHERE l.section = 'WL';
```